# Consulta con varios registros devuelve solo un registro

Tags: php, sql

Me devuelve solo un registro y en mi BBDD hay 3. Sospecho que el problema puede estar en la consulta, con el tema de concatenar tablas.

Aquí mi sentencia:

```
SELECT 
  productos.nombre, 
  productos.name, 
  productos.precio,
  categorias.name as cat_name,
  categorias.nombre cat_nombre,
  SUM(productos.precio) as total_price 
FROM wishlist, productos, categorias 
WHERE wishlist.cod_producto=productos.cod_producto 
  AND productos.cod_categoria=categorias.cod_categoria 
  AND wishlist.cod_user = '$cod_user'
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Está bien que recurras a la comunidad para preguntar y recibir propuestas que ayuden a responder tu inquietud, pero para que la respuesta pueda ser de buena calidad y logre responder tu inquietud necesitamos que nos especifiques en mejor medida el problema que está relacionado con tu inquietud. Además, necesitas incluir algún ejemplo de lo que necesitas y explicar más detalladamente tu inquietud. Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Por favor, incluye los datos y la estructura de la tabla, **como texto**, sin capturas de pantalla. Evaular la consulta por sí sola es complicado... Lo otro: en tu pregunta no hay código PHP y usas la etiqueta [php]

Answer (score 0):

Si incluyes una función de agregado como `SUM` lo mas recomendable es que uses un `GROUP BY` también

```
SELECT 
  productos.nombre, 
  productos.name, 
  categorias.name as cat_name,
  categorias.nombre cat_nombre,
  SUM(productos.precio) as total_price 
FROM wishlist, productos, categorias 
WHERE wishlist.cod_producto=productos.cod_producto 
  AND productos.cod_categoria=categorias.cod_categoria 
  AND wishlist.cod_user = '$cod_user'
GROUP BY
  productos.nombre, 
  productos.name, 
  categorias.name,
  categorias.nombre
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya me devuelven todos los registros de esa consulta. supongo que al hacer la suma de una de las columnas, solo me mostraba el primer registro con la suma de todos. Lo que pasa ahora es que no me hace la suma de los campos, pero tengo solución para ello. Muchas gracias

Comment: OK. Perfecto....